# Remotely execute a Spark job on an HDInsight cluster

Tags: azure, apache-spark, remote-access, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to automatically launch a *Spark* job on an *HDInsight* cluster from *Microsoft Azure*. I am aware that several methods exist to automate *Hadoop* job submission (provided by *Azure* itself), but so far I have not been able to found a way to remotely run a *Spark* job withouth setting a RDP with the master instance.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark-jobserver provides a RESTful interface for submitting and managing Apache Spark jobs, jars, and job contexts.

https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver

My solution is using both Scheduler and Spark-jobserver to launch the Spark-job periodically.

Comment: Well, after a long time, it seems we will finally have something to start working with, although I've already switched to AWS.

Comment: Good choice man :) However, just mark my answer for next guys :)

Comment: I am testing Spark-jobserver, before marking it as the final answer. However, for what I am seeing, I expect to mark it sooner than later. :)

Answer (score 2):

At the moment of this writing, it seems there is no *official* way of achieving this. So far, however, I have been able to somehow remotely run *Spark* jobs using an *Oozie shell* workflow. It is nothing but a patch, but so far it has been useful for me. These are the steps I have followed:

### Prerequisites

- Microsoft Powershell
- Azure Powershell

### Process

#### Define an Oozie workflow *.xml* file:

```
<workflow-app name="myWorkflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2">
  <start to = "myAction"/>
  <action name="myAction">
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <exec>myScript.cmd</exec>
            <file>wasb://myContainer@myAccount.blob.core.windows.net/myScript.cmd#myScript.cmd</file>
            <file>wasb://myContainer@myAccount.blob.core.windows.net/mySpark.jar#mySpark.jar</file>
        </shell>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Shell action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Note that it is not possible to identify on which *HDInsight* node is going to be executed the script, so it is necessary to put it, along with the *Spark* application *.jar*, on the *wasb* repository. It is then redirectioned to the local directory on which the *Oozie* job is executing.

#### Define the custom script

```
C:\apps\dist\spark-1.2.0\bin\spark-submit --class spark.azure.MainClass
                                          --master yarn-cluster 
                                          --deploy-mode cluster 
                                          --num-executors 3 
                                          --executor-memory 2g 
                                          --executor-cores 4 
                                          mySpark.jar
```

It is necessary to upload both the *.cmd* and the *Spark .jar* to the wasb repository (a process that it is not included in this answer), concretely to the direction pointed in the workflow:

`wasb://myContainer@myAccount.blob.core.windows.net/`

#### Define the powershell script

The powershell script is very much taken from the official *[Oozie on HDInsight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn749844.aspx)* tutorial. I am not including the script on this answer due to its almost absolute sameness with my approach.

I have made a new suggestion on the [azure feedback portal](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217335-hdinsight/suggestions/7101515-support-remote-spark-job-submission) indicating the need of official support for remote Spark job submission.

Answer (score 1):

Updated on 8/17/2016:
Our spark cluster offering now includes a Livy server that provides a rest service to submit a spark job. You can automate spark job via Azure Data Factory as well.

---

Original post: 
1) Remote job submission for spark is currently not supported.

2) If you want to automate setting a master every time ( i.e. adding --master yarn-client every time you execute), you can set the value in %SPARK_HOME\conf\spark-defaults.conf file with following config:

spark.master yarn-client

You can find more info on spark-defaults.conf on apache spark website.

3) Use cluster customization feature if you want to add this automatically to spark-defaults.conf file at deployment time.