# Using Apache spark with HDinsight cluster from a web application

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

I am currently trying to create a big data processing web application using Apache spark, which I have successfully installed on my HDinsight cluster.  I have written Mapreduce programs in C# connecting to my cluster in the past and have been able to run applications in which I connect to my cluster by putting in my account name, storage key, etc...  I have looked around the web and it seems that the only way to submit a job with apache spark is to connect to your cluster using a RDP but then there is no way I could incorporate that into a web app (easily. I am new to dealing with clusters/big data).  Is it possible to connect to my cluster in a similar manner that I do when I run mapreduce jobs?

I was also thinking that maybe it would be possible to write this within mapreduce, in which I would already be in the context of my cluster.  Would that be possible in any way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing spark via script actions then Spark specific ports cannot be open outside of the cluster. You can use Spark through VNets though. If you setup a VNET between your end point and the cluster, you can use native spark protocols for remote job submission/querying.  It's also possible using [Oozie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28542415/remotely-execute-a-spark-job-on-an-hdinsight-cluster)

You could also investigate using the newly announced preview Spark clusters and C# job submissions.